# What can I use for taking integer input instead of scanf in C?

Tags: c, scanf, user-input

I am learning C. I am currently using **CLion** IDE for practicing C. I used **codeblocks** and **vs code** before and was ok. But Clion is showing an warning for `scanf()`. Is there anything that I can use instead of scanf for taking input like **integer, float and double**?

It will be very grateful for me to know.

Comment: Please share what the warning is.

Answer (score 4):

Do not use `scanf()` for user inputs, it has several drawbacks.

Use [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead.

Here's a [nice read](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html) (off-site resource) on the "why" part.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fgets()`  .
It is a bug in CLion IDE for scanf function.
It would be more appreciated if you could tell what is the warning you are getting .

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `scanf`, you have a couple of choices:
You can use a combination of `fgets` and `strtol` (for integer inputs) or `strtod` (for floating point inputs).  Example (untested):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
...
char buf[12]; // 10 digits, plus sign, plus terminator
char *chk; // points to first character *not* converted by strtol

if ( !fgets( buf, sizeof buf, stdin ) )
{
  fprintf( stderr, "Error on input\n" );
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

long value = strtol( buf, &chk, 10 ); // 10 means we expect decimal input
if ( !isspace( *chk ) && *chk != 0 )
{
  fprintf( stderr, "Found non-decimal character %c in %s\n", *chk, buf );
  fprintf( stderr, "value may have been truncated\n" );
}
printf( "Input value is %ld\n", value );
```

You can use `getchar` to read individual characters, use `isdigit` to check each, and build the value manually.  Example (also untested):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
...
int value = 0;
for ( int c = getchar(); isdigit( c ); c = getchar() ) // again, assumes decimal input
{
  value *= 10;
  value += c - '0';
}
printf( "Value is %d\n", value );
```